# Installing module using Anaconda caused issues on my Virtual Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I attempted to update `pandas_datareader` on my Python 3.5.2 virtual Environment using Anaconda like this:

```
conda activate myenv
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

But now I can't use the environment in any of the IDEs I use, neither in CMD. This is the outcome when I use `conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at C:\xx\xx\Anaconda3\envs\myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appdirs                   1.4.3                     <pip>
argon2-cffi               20.1.0                    <pip>
asn1crypto                1.4.0                      py_0    anaconda
asn1crypto                0.24.0                    <pip>
async-generator           1.10                      <pip>
attrs                     20.2.0                    <pip>
backcall                  0.1.0                    py35_0
backcall                  0.2.0                     <pip>
blas                      1.0                         mkl    anaconda
bleach                    3.2.1                     <pip>
blosc                     1.5.1                     <pip>
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0    anaconda
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1    anaconda
certifi                   2020.6.20                 <pip>
cffi                      1.14.3                    <pip>
cffi                      1.11.5           py35h74b6da3_1    anaconda
chardet                   3.0.4                     <pip>
chardet                   3.0.4                    py35_1    anaconda
cloudpickle               1.4.1                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
cryptography              2.1.4            py35h8ead9e0_0    anaconda
cryptography              2.2                       <pip>
Cython                    0.29.21                   <pip>
DateTime                  4.2                       <pip>
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                     <pip>
dill                      0.2.7.1                   <pip>
eikon                     0.1.12                    <pip>
entrypoints               0.3                       <pip>
et-xmlfile                1.0.1                     <pip>
findatapy                 0.5                       <pip>
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1    anaconda
idna                      2.6                       <pip>
idna                      2.10                       py_0    anaconda
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                     <pip>
inflection                0.3.1                     <pip>
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254    anaconda
ipykernel                 4.10.0                   py35_0    anaconda
ipykernel                 5.3.4                     <pip>
ipython                   7.18.1                    <pip>
ipython                   6.5.0                    py35_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                     <pip>
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py35ha709e79_0
jdcal                     1.3                       <pip>
jedi                      0.12.1                   py35_0
jedi                      0.17.2                    <pip>
Jinja2                    2.11.2                    <pip>
jupyter-client            6.1.7                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.6.3                     <pip>
jupyter_client            5.3.3                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2                     <pip>
libiconv                  1.15             vc14h29686d3_5  [vc14]  anaconda
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libxml2                   2.9.4            vc14h8fd0f11_5  [vc14]  anaconda
libxslt                   1.1.29           vc14hf85b8d4_5  [vc14]  anaconda
llvmlite                  0.22.0                    <pip>
lxml                      4.1.1            py35ha957a02_0    anaconda
lxml                      4.2.0                     <pip>
MarkupSafe                1.1.1                     <pip>
mistune                   0.8.4                     <pip>
mkl                       2020.2                      256    anaconda
mkl-fft                   1.2.0                     <pip>
mkl-random                1.1.1                     <pip>
mkl-service               2.3.0                     <pip>
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py35hdbbee80_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.0.1            py35h77b88f5_1    anaconda
more-itertools            4.1.0                     <pip>
multiprocess              0.70.5                    <pip>
multiprocessing-on-dill   3.5.0a4                   <pip>
mysql-connector-python    8.0.12                    <pip>
nbclient                  0.5.0                     <pip>
nbconvert                 6.0.7                     <pip>
nbformat                  5.0.7                     <pip>
ndg-httpsclient           0.4.4                     <pip>
nest-asyncio              1.4.1                     <pip>
notebook                  6.1.4                     <pip>
numba                     0.37.0                    <pip>
numpy                     1.19.2                    <pip>
numpy                     1.15.2           py35ha559c80_0    anaconda
numpy                     1.14.2                    <pip>
numpy-base                1.15.2           py35h8128ebf_0    anaconda
oauthlib                  2.0.6                     <pip>
openpyxl                  2.5.1                     <pip>
openssl                   1.0.2m           vc14h7f35f9e_0  [vc14]  anaconda
packaging                 20.4                      <pip>
pandas                    0.25.3                    <pip>
pandas                    0.23.4           py35h830ac7b_0    anaconda
pandas-datareader         0.9.0                      py_0    anaconda
pandas-market-calendars   1.4.1                     <pip>
pandocfilters             1.4.2                     <pip>
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
patsy                     0.5.0                     <pip>
pickleshare               0.7.5                     <pip>
pickleshare               0.7.4            py35h2f9f535_0
pip                       20.2.3                    <pip>
pip                       9.0.1            py35h691316f_4
pip                       18.1                      <pip>
prometheus-client         0.8.0                     <pip>
prompt-toolkit            3.0.7                     <pip>
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py35h89c7cb4_0
pyasn1                    0.4.2                     <pip>
pycparser                 2.18                      <pip>
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2    anaconda
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0
pyOpenSSL                 17.5.0                    <pip>
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py35h75c5b16_0    anaconda
pyparsing                 2.4.7                     <pip>
pypiwin32                 223                       <pip>
pyreadline                2.1                       <pip>
pyrsistent                0.17.3                    <pip>
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py35_0    anaconda
python                    3.5.4               h1357f44_23
python-dateutil           2.7.0                     <pip>
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0    anaconda
pytz                      2018.3                    <pip>
pywin32                   227                       <pip>
pywin32                   224                       <pip>
pywinpty                  0.5.7                     <pip>
pyzmq                     17.1.2                    <pip>
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py35hfa6e2cd_0
Quandl                    3.3.0                     <pip>
redis                     2.10.6                    <pip>
requests                  2.18.4                    <pip>
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0    anaconda
requests-file             1.4.3                     <pip>
requests-ftp              0.3.1                     <pip>
requests-oauthlib         0.8.0                     <pip>
scipy                     1.0.0                     <pip>
Send2Trash                1.5.0                     <pip>
setuptools                50.3.0.post20201006           <pip>
setuptools                38.4.0                   py35_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_2
simplegeneric             0.8.1                     <pip>
six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
six                       1.11.0                   py35_1
six                       1.15.0                    <pip>
spyder-kernels            0.2.6                    py35_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                     <pip>
statsmodels               0.8.0                     <pip>
TBB                       0.1                       <pip>
terminado                 0.8.3                     <pip>
testpath                  0.4.4                     <pip>
tornado                   5.1.1            py35hfa6e2cd_0
tornado                   6.0.4                     <pip>
traitlets                 4.3.2            py35h09b975b_0
traitlets                 5.0.4                     <pip>
twython                   3.6.0                     <pip>
urllib3                   1.22                      <pip>
urllib3                   1.23                     py35_0    anaconda
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wcwidth                   0.1.9                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                     <pip>
websocket-client          0.47.0                    <pip>
wheel                     0.30.0           py35h38a90bc_1
wheel                     0.35.1                    <pip>
win-unicode-console       0.5                       <pip>
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py35_1    anaconda
win_unicode_console       0.5              py35h56988b5_0
wincertstore              0.2              py35hfebbdb8_0
wincertstore              0.2                       <pip>
wrapt                     1.10.11                   <pip>
zeromq                    4.2.5                he025d50_1
zipp                      3.3.0                     <pip>
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zope.interface            4.4.3                     <pip>
```

I can run `import numpy as np` but when I run `import pandas as pd` I get the following:

> from pandas.core.dtypes.common import ( ImportError: cannot import
> name 'ensure_object'

The list implies I've used different sources for installing packages within my Virtual Environment, perhaps that's creating a conflict?

What may I do to correct such error? Would delete and re-installing Pandas would do? If so, how should I proceed about? Should I do it with pip?

Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I ended up solving this by rolling back the changes I made using `conda list --revisions` to find out until which previous set up I had to roll back to, then afterwards I ran `conda install --revision N` (where N is the revision you want to trace back to). Suppose the changes you made are `rev 4`, you want to undo them, and sit back again under `rev 3` (your previously "known and working" environment you had), so you run `conda install --revision 3` for that case.

Afterwards I re-installed `pandas_datareader` with `python -m pip install pandas-datareader` and everything went good again.

Thanks anyways and I hope if someone else runs into this issue, can find this post valuable.